# Entity Framework and constraints

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, constraints

I want to write constraints for DB. I.e. my entity class has 2 fields:

```
public int DriverCompensationTypeId { get; set; }
public decimal? CompensationRate { get; set; }
```

I want to specify, that:

1. Only allowed values for `DriverCompensationTypeId` are `0, 1, 2, 3`
2. `CompensationRate` always should be `null` if `DriverCompensationTypeId == 0` and should be not `null` in all other cases.

How to write these constraints?

Comment: You can define enums in your model and set property type to the enum

Comment: @FelixCastor but for second case?

Comment: That is more business logic and shouldn't be handled by your database.

Comment: @FelixCastor I want to have correct data in db. To deny for another db operator write invalid data

Comment: Your application should prevent that.  Maybe put something in the `DriverCompensationTypes` property's setter in your model that adjusts the compensationRate for instance.

Comment: @FelixCastor not only my application can use DB

Comment: @FelixCastor, also, using enum instead of int nothing changed

Comment: @OlegSh I agree with FelixCastor that the way it is written now, this should be handled in the business layer. An alternative would be to make this a foreign key and point to another table where your options are `0,1,2,3` which would make sure there are only those numbers in the DB as inserting anything else causes an exception

Answer (score 0):

The enum Felix Castor mentioned is to force the allowable values for DriverCompensationTypeId to be 0 through 3.  It is still stored as int, that what enums do :)

Using a property setter for DriverCompensationTypeId is one way to set CompensationRate to null via code.

(SQL Server) Creating Add/Update Triggers that validate and/or adjust the data before it is stored is another.  Code changes consist of handling database errors.

Putting business rules in your business layer instead of your entity is the better way to go.  You could then have in your mapping/validation code...

```
CompensationRate = DriverCompensationTypeId == 0 ? null, CompensationRate;
```

of course, if you decide to use the enum you would substitute the enum value in place of the "0"

**Add-on**: You have much more flexibility *how* to implement a business rule when creating a new entity/attribute.  Once the attribute(field) exists, then you are a little more constrained by the effort involved.  The principle "Separation of Concerns" pretty much clumps like with like (data access for one entity with data access for other entities).

Business rules should care less about how or where data is stored or accessed.  If you adopt this principle/pattern, then you most likely would want all of the validations & business logic grouped into a single layer, which I find easier to locate and maintain later on.

This does NOT mean you don't do client-side validation, that helps to give immediate **quick** feedback to the user without involving a round-trip to the server.  But you **always** have to have server-side validations to prevent a variety of hacks.  UI = convenience, Server = security/consistency.

Comment: then we can say, that no necessary to create PK/FK and control it on business layer...

Comment: Added more explanation in answer to be responsive to comment.